# temp value is always show new value instead of old value

Tags: c#

Can someone help me with this code its suppose to change the Lft and Rgt properties on a department in the selected_deparmtents list. The problem I'm having is getting the old value or previous value in the temp variable which holds the previous departments Lft and Rgt properties. What it does is show the updated value on the temp.Lft property which is wrong I want the previous Lft property to do the calulation. Does anyone know how I can get around this problem

```
int counter = 0;
int lft = department.Lft;
int rgt;
Department temp;
List<Department> clones = new List<Department>(selected_departments);                   

foreach (Department dept in selected_departments)
{
    if (counter < 1)
    {
       rgt = (dept.Rgt - dept.Lft);                            
       dept.Lft = lft;
       dept.Rgt = lft + rgt;
    }
    else
    {                                                        
        temp = clones.ElementAt(counter - 1); // <-- incorrect 
        // previous departments value should be old value 
        lft = lft + (dept.Lft - temp.Lft);// here temp.Lft always show the newly updated value
        rgt = lft + (dept.Rgt - dept.Lft);

        dept.Lft = lft;
        dept.Rgt = rgt;
    }
    db.Entry(dept).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();            
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Counter is working and loops to the next record in the else statement but it always shows newly updated element instead of old element in clones

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're not actually getting a deep enough copy in the `clones` `List`. Instead, it has a copy of all of the references to departments, so when you update one, it changes the value in both.

This looks to be fixable by the following, assuming your `Department` constructor takes a parameter for left and right:

```
List<Department> clones = new List<Department>(selected_departments.Count);                   
for (int i = 0; i < selected_departments.Count; i++)
{
    clones.Add(new Department(selected_departments[i].Lft, selected_departments[i].Rgt));
}
```